# How do I solve TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the code, I just don't know why the error keeps showing up even after reading the past answers about it.

```
import random
rand = random.sample(range(10), 1)
print(rand)

guess = input('Try guessing a number between 0-10! ')


for num in str(guess):
    if rand > guess:
        print('The number is too low! Try again!')
    elif rand < guess:
        print('The number is too high! Try again!')
    else:
        print("You got it!")
```

Comment: `random.sample` gives you a *list*, in this case with a single item in it; if you just want a single item on its own try `random.choice`, or access that single item with `rand[0]`.

Comment: Why is this post tagged with Python3 but `guess` is an int according to the error? Shouldn't it be a string?

Comment: you should probably convert your user input to a number so you can use < > to compare it to your random. Conversion is done via `int(guess)`  - you might need to guard with try/except if user inputs something like "ten"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
rand = random.sample(range(10), 1)
```

With

```
rand = random.randint(0, 10)
```

Your code is trying to compare a list with a string. You need to compare two of the same. Also try making guess an integer first:

```
guess = int(input('Try guessing a number between 0-10! '))
```

and removing the str(guess) - leave just guess as it is now an integer

Answer (score 0):

for this problem, simply replace `random.sample(range(10), 1)` with `random.randint(1,11)` or `random.choice(range(10))`. `random.sample` returns a list. You want to return a integer, so you can do a comparison.
Besides, your error description does not seem correct. It seems you should get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in <module>
    if rand>guess:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > str()
```

And to avoid this, use the `int()` function to convert your input to a number and make the other change from above.